# Swift 3.0 migration error: Type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol type 'IndexPath'

Tags: ios, swift, migration, swift3

I am trying to migrate my code base to swift 3.0 using xCode. There are few issues which I am not able to understand.

Issue: `Type 'Element' constrained to non-protocol type 'IndexPath'`

[image]

In left side of error navigation panel it's shows only below errors. I am not able to understand for which line of code or branch of code causes the error.

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this please.

> UPDATE

After struggling a lot I am stuck at these issues.

[image]

> UPDATE

Thank you all for your help. Now I faced only the following issues.

[image]

Few of you are asking to post the source code but Xcode didn't show any kind of warning or error on pages. There are few generics

```
private extension Array where Element: IndexPath {

    func indexOf(_ indexPath: IndexPath) -> Int {
        var counter = 0
        for object in self {
            if object.section == indexPath.section && object.row == indexPath.row {
                return counter
            }
            counter += 1
        }
        return 0
    }
}


fileprivate func < <T : Comparable>(lhs: T?, rhs: T?) -> Bool {
  switch (lhs, rhs) {
  case let (l?, r?):
    return l < r
  case (nil, _?):
    return true
  default:
    return false
  }
}
```

Comment: se this once http://blog.krzyzanowskim.com/2015/10/07/generic-array-uint8/

Comment: NSIndexPath is now IndexPath in swift3. it would help if you share your code rather than just the error. see apple docs https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/indexpath

Comment: If that is the case then the same error is showing in `CreateAccountViewController` there are neither use of NSIndexPath nor anything related with IndexPath.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can use a specific type with a different syntax:

```
extension Array where Element == IndexPath {
```

As opposed to the more historic syntax for protocols:

```
extension Array where Element: Indexable {
```

Previously you could / had to shuffle around problems by creating a protocol, something like:

```
protocol Indexable {
    var row: Int { get }
    var section: Int { get }
}

extension IndexPath: Indexable {}

extension Array where Element: Indexable {
    ...
```

Comment: Answering my own question (yes!): https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-install-a-beta-version-of-swift

Comment: Thanks, might be worth it to edit to remove the historical note or at least drop it below, perhaps?

Comment: @DanRosenstark yes, probably about time for a clean up :)